# Index of MorphologicalGraph[] and GraphEmbedding[] do not match

Tags: graphs-and-networks

I am planning to automatically detect number of bifurcation of each node in tree structure from images. At first we obtain tree graph from image using

```
branchGraph = MorphologicalGraph[image, VertexLabels -> "Name"]
```

Next we try to obtain coordinates of each nodes using `GraphEmbedding[]`.

```
nodeCoordinates = GraphEmbedding[branchGraph]
```

We can obtain coordinate by this, but correlation between node index in the graph and location in the list is not identical.

```
graphEmbeddingIndex = 
 Show[Graphics[
   Table[{Red, Text[i, nodeCoordinates[[i]]]}, {i, 1, 
     Length[nodeCoordinates]}]]]

Show[branchGraph, graphEmbeddingIndex]
```

[image: Black:node index, Red: graphEmbedding index]

Is there any good way to know the coordinate of certain node in a graph?

Sincerely,

Takashi Miura.

Answer (score 1):

```
img = Import["https://i.stack.imgur.com/U5yMN.png"]
```

[image]

```
g = MorphologicalGraph[img, VertexLabels -> "Name", ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

The vertex coordinates given by `GraphEmbedding[g]` are in the order of `VertexList[g]`. That is, `GraphEmbedding[g][[i]]` corresponds to the vertex `VertexList[g][[i]]`, which, in turn, is not necessarily equal to `i`, since the vertices in `VertexList[g]` are in the order used in the graph `g`:

```
VertexList[g]
```

> {1, 4, 2, 3, 5, 11, 6, 7, 9, 12, 8, 13, 14, 10, 15, 16, 17, 18, 19, 20}

So if you change your definition of `nodeCoordinates` to

```
nodeCoordinates = GraphEmbedding[g][[Ordering[VertexList[g]]]];
```

or to

```
nodeCoordinates = PropertyValue[{g, VertexIndex[g, #]}, VertexCoordinates] & /@ 
  VertexList[g];
```

then we get the correct mapping using the modified `nodeCoordinates` in your `graphEmbeddingIndex` or, more directly,

```
Show[g, Epilog -> Table[{Red, Text[Style[i, 16], nodeCoordinates[[i]]]}, 
  {i, 1, Length[nodeCoordinates]}], ImagePadding -> 20]
```

[image]

Comment: This worked fine! Thank you very much!

Comment: @TakashiMiura, my pleasure. Welcome to mma.se.